# Show my own text in lock screen in android 5 or 6

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow

I want to show my own text (huge font size)

**for example:**

My name and surname or everything other in lock screen in android 5 or 6.

Is it possible, or only android notifications can be showed in lock screen?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible

Not via the Android SDK. It is possible that some device manufacturers have an option for this, through some proprietary SDK that works with some subset of their devices.